# Inserting date in Mysql (codename one)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert a Date object in mysql database, which has a Date type in the database as well. I am having problems inserting the date .

I have tried this code, but it seems codename one have a problem with it:

```
dateString s;
s = date.getCurrentMonth() + "/" + date.getCurrentDay() + "/" + date.getCurrentYear();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date startDate = (Date) formatter.parse(s);
```

Please can you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: There are many examples online of how to insert data into a database.  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: mysql isn't a Codename One product and so you should tag this SQL, mysql etc. You should also include the details of what you tried to do in the question otherwise your question will get downvoted and deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to format it. Just use this SQL Date Object instead of Date object from java.util package.

```
import java.sql.Date

// Creating a date object.
Date date = new Date();
```

In a database, make sure the data type of attribute 'date' is selected as "Date" also, not VarChar. Simply pass this sql package Date object into the database through query. :) It will save the date in a format.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Please do remember to share your remarks after trying it, and don't forget to accept the answer, if it works for you. :)